# Draw and compare the likelihood using R

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, math-software, statistical-inference

The following shows the heart rate (in beats/minute) of a person, measured throughout the day:

73, 75, 84, 76, 93, 79, 85, 80, 76, 78, 80.

Assume the data are an iid sample from $\mathrm{N}(\theta, \sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2$ is known at the observed sample variance. Denote the ordered values by $x_{(1)}, \cdots, x_{(11)}$. Draw using R and compare the likelihood of $\theta$ if

the whole data $x_1, \cdots, x_{11}$ are reported;

only the sample mean $\bar x$ is reported;

only the sample median $x_{(6)}$ is reported;

only the minimum $x_{(1)}$ and maximum $x_{(11)}$ are reported;

only the lowest two values $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(2)}$ are reported.

Comment: Please could you tell what have you tried?

Comment: @SergioParreiras, I tried this in R:
beats <- sort(c(73,75,84, 76, 93, 79,85, 80, 76 ,78,80))
 v <- var(beats)
 theta <- seq(0,200,1)
 gauss <- function(x){prod(dnorm(beats,x,v))}
 like <- sapply(theta, gauss)
 like <- like/max(like)
 plot (theta,like,col=1 )
is this the right way?

Comment: I don't use R (I would solve this using Maple and paper) but I am sure some one will help. But if the question is related to syntax of a particular package, this may not be the best place to ask. Have you tried the stats stack exchange site (cross validated)?